# Auto add meeting app to all meetings in tenant

Tags: microsoft-graph, microsoft-teams

I have a Teams meeting app that can be added to Teams meetings. I need to ensure that the app is installed as soon as the event is created throughout the tenant in any user's calendar. Is there any global subscription or Teams app setup policy to achieve this?